# How can I access data on columns from a specific table from a JOIN query statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

Suppose this is the SQL

```
 SELECT * FROM core AS t1 
 LEFT JOIN supply AS t2
 ON t1.sid = t2.id
 LEFT JOIN dingus AS t3
 ON t1.did = t3.id
 LEFT JOIN covid AS t4
 ON t1.cid = t4.id
 LEFT JOIN mom AS t4
 ON t1.mid = t4.id
```

Here's some code

Normally getting the data from the database would be something like this

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM core AS t1 
 LEFT JOIN supply AS t2
 ON t1.sid = t2.id
 LEFT JOIN dingus AS t3
 ON t1.did = t3.id
 LEFT JOIN covid AS t4
 ON t1.cid = t4.id
 LEFT JOIN mom AS t4
 ON t1.mid = t4.id;";
$sts  = self::$db->prepare($sql);
$sts->execute();
$rows = $sts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); // Or what ever it is, 
// it could be PDO::FETCH_ACCOS, or others, but I couldn't find the right one.
$sts->closeCursor();
return $rows
```

Then you loop though all the rows with

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   echo  $row[0];
   /// ... and so on
}
```

Are there any ways to get data from column of a specific joined table?

Something like this...

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{ 
      // This represents data of the first column of the table dingus
      echo $row->t2[0]; // Something like this..
}
```

Comment: You can't modify SQL? Ideally you would list columns you want to select, not use `*`.

Comment: I was thinking about that but there's already so many columns, and there could be more tables in the future. I think it would be a lot easier if we can just access the data of the specific joined tables instead of counting the array index. Thank for the reply by the way.

Comment: Is this an issue where there are columns of the same name (such as id) in multiple tables?

Comment: Yes t1, t2, t3, t4 have BOTH different and the same column name. Like column 'id' is part of all t1, t2, t3, and t4, but for example column 'name' could be in just t1, and t2 , or column 'place' could be in just t2 and t4. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I already have my solution ,and that is to count the index of the returned array, but let's see if you guys have better ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Then save yourself and anyone who might be working on this project in the future potential headaches and write the query explicitly naming the columns you need and giving an alias to any repeating names. It's better to do this once (and before the query grows further) than having to blindly debug n times in the future. If you count the index it works now, but what if new columns are added to one of the tables?

Comment: Or other solutions is to change the database structure, and build some kind of JSON string, and write the PHP code to process it.

Comment: The canonical solution has already been given. Don't use `SELECT *` and assign aliases to any duplicate column names.

Comment: Ok, I just changed my mind. It will only join 4 tables. No more. Thanks